# How to get an iframe containing a pdf have auto height on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ipad, iframe

I am developing a web app which needs to display a pdf within an iframe. I have a div surrounding the iframe to control scrolling as to not interfere with the rest of the app.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;">
    <iframe src="resource/southernNorthSea.pdf" width="100%" height="auto">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

On the ipad, the height of the iframe is about 20% of the screen. Is there a way to set the height of the iframe equal to the height of it's contents?